# Multiple Where In's in Active Record or SQL

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord

Sorry about the title of the question, I wasn't sure how to word it for this issue.

I have a table that would look something like this:

```
entry_id | cat_id
---------+-------
1        | 23
1        | 17
1        | 34
1        | 11
2        | 25
2        | 28
2        | 90
2        | 23
```

Then I have different arrays for categories

```
$cats1 = [23, 46, 67]
$cats2 = [34, 28, 91]
```

I need to get back the `entry_id`'s that have `cat_id`'s in both arrays, but if I do

```
->where_in('cat_id', $cats1)->where_in('cat_id', $cats2)
```

obviously this doesn't work because no row has more than one `cat_id` associated with it. In this case, the `entry_id` I would want back would be `1`, as it contains a value from the first `array(23)`, as well as one from the second `array(34)`.

I can't use `or_where` because the results are not accurate. I'm fine using a straight SQL select statement, but I'm wondering if there is even a way for me to achieve this type of query on a table like this. I'm not an SQL pro so any guidance would be appreciated.

I've currently got it working using another solution where I get the `entry_id`'s from the first `where_in`, then have another query do a `where_in` those `id`'s and `where_in` the second array of cats, but I would prefer to do the whole query in one shot.

This is in PHP.

Comment: Do you have an `entry` table, too?

Comment: Yes I have an entry table too that contains the entry information, if you think a join there is better. If not I will test your other answer and mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Update, correction:) `DISTINCT` is needed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.entry_id 
FROM tableX AS a
  JOIN tableX AS b
    ON b.entry_id = a.entry_id 
WHERE a.cat_id IN (23, 46, 67)
  AND b.cat_id IN (34, 28, 91) ;
```

---

If you have an `entry` table, you could also use either a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.entry_id 
FROM entry AS e
  JOIN tableX AS a
    ON a.entry_id = e.entry_id 
  JOIN tableX AS b
    ON b.entry_id = e.entry_id 
WHERE a.cat_id IN (23, 46, 67)
  AND b.cat_id IN (34, 28, 91) ;
```

or `EXISTS` correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT e.entry_id 
FROM entry AS e
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT *
        FROM tableX AS a
        WHERE a.entry_id = e.entry_id 
          AND a.cat_id IN (23, 46, 67)
      )
  AND EXISTS 
      ( SELECT *
        FROM tableX AS b
        WHERE b.entry_id = e.entry_id 
          AND b.cat_id IN (34, 28, 91)
      ) ;
```

Comment: This is excellent stuff. I'm going to play with them to see which suits best, but at worst I'll just use the raw SQL you've provided. Thanks a lot for your help